# How to select between 'StaticText' fields with requests_html

Tags: python, html, python-requests-html

So I want to print only two fields of StaticText of a website. Those two fields are both within '< p >'. In Chrome's inspector it looks something like this:

```
<li>
<p>not needed field<p>
</li>

<li>
<h3> not needed field </h3>
<p>not needed field</p>
<p>not needed field</p>
<p>select this field</p>
<p>select this field</p>
<p>not needed field</p>
</li>
```

So above the fields I need, there are some < p > fields that I dont want to select. Depending on the page, sometimes there are more < p > fields above these fields (on the first < li >), so the order changes. That's why this don't work for me:

```
nr = 0
for p in r.html.find("p"):
  if nr == 3:
   print(p)
  elif nr == 4:
   print(p)
  nr=nr+1
```

Is there any way I can select only those 2 < p > fields without having to worry about the changing order?

Comment: To generalize you must find something that identify the < p > elements that you are interested in, do they contain some specific class/id or even some specific information that you can look for?

Comment: They do not have a class id assigned. I checked properties they all seem to be the same. In the accessibility tree they are under list items as: StaticText "field value"

Comment: All of them tagged as StaticText or only the ones which are of relevance?

Comment: All 5 on the second < li > after < h3 > are StaticText, so also the irrelevant ones

Comment: Themsen the task would require some kind of classification or machine learning to know if the field is relevant or not. To make this purely programmatically you need some kind of identification which you seem to be missing.